# In Reality Composer, how can I stop a sound?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

Say I have 2 buttons, each triggers a piece of music.

How do I have Button A stop the music that was triggered by Button B and vice versa?

Not seeing the option for Sound, Music, or Ambience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Playing/Stopping audio with one 3D button

In macOS RC, create 2 scenes – first with `stop` button, and second with `play` button.

[image]

Then, apply the `Tap` trigger and `Change Scene` action to custom Behavior of the 1st scene:

[image]

And apply the corresponding triggers and actions to 2 simultaneous behaviors of the 2nd scene:

[image]

---

[image]

Now, when you tap the buttons, sound `plays`/`stops` as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works. However I found that creating multiple scenes bloats the resulting `.reality` file too much. My main object is 20MB, and with 3 scenes it becomes a >60MB reality file. I think we're going to have to look elsewhere; Reality Composer is too limited.

Comment: It’s hard to argue with this statement – ​​you’re right.